# Testing ChainlinkClient callbacks - how to bypass recordChainlinkFulfillment?

Tags: testing, solidity, chainlink

I've got a Chainlink client contract which makes a DirectRequest to an oracle. The oracle does its thing and then returns the answer via the typical callback selector passed in via the `ChainlinkRequest`. It all works well, but I'd like to write some tests that test the callback implementation

My client contract is as follows:

```
contract PriceFeed is Ownable, ChainlinkClient {
  function updatePrice() onlyOwner returns (bytes32 requestId) {
    // makes Chainlink request specifying callback via this.requestCallback.selector
  }

  function requestCallback(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _newPrice) public
        recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId) {
    price = _newPrice;
  }
}
```

The problem arises when the test code calls `requestCallback(...)` and the code hits the `recordChainlinkFulfillment(...)` modifier. The `ChainlinkClient` complains that the `requestId` being passed in by the test below isn't in the underling private `pendingRequests` mapping maintained by the `ChainlinkClient`.

The simplified version of `ChainlinkClient` looks like this:

```
contract ChainlinkClient {
  mapping(bytes32 => address) private pendingRequests;

  modifier recordChainlinkFulfillment(bytes32 _requestId) {
    require(msg.sender == pendingRequests[_requestId], "Source must be the oracle of the request");
    delete pendingRequests[_requestId];
    emit ChainlinkFulfilled(_requestId);
    _;
  }
}
```

My Foundry/Solidity test is as follows:

```
contract PriceFeedTest is Test {
  function testInitialCallback() public {
      priceFeed.requestCallback("abc123", 1000000); // fails on this line
      assertEq(1000000, priceFeed.price(), "Expecting price to be 1000000");
  }
}
```

The code fails on first line of the `testInitialCallback()` line with: `Source must be the oracle of the request`

How can I trick the ChainklinkClient into allowing my callback to get past the modifier check? AFAIK I can't access and pre-populate the private `pendingRequests` mapping. Is there another way?

I know that Foundry provides Cheatcodes to help in testing and there's a stdstorage cheatcode, but I'm not familiar on how to construct a call to stdstorage to override pendingRequests if thats even possible with a cheatcode.

```
contract PriceFeedTest is Test {
  function testInitialCallback2() public {
      stdstore
          .target(address(priceFeed))
          .sig("pendingRequests()")
          .with_key("abc123")
          .checked_write(address(this));

      priceFeed.requestCallback("abc123", 1000000);
      assertEq(1000000, priceFeed.price(), "Expecting price to be 1000000");
  }
}
```

The above code throws the following error:  `No storage use detected for target`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute the `updatePrice` function in your test, you should be able to strip out the `requestId` from the transaction receipt event. Once you have that, you can then use it in your call to `requestCallback`. Check out this [example unit test](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/hardhat-starter-kit/blob/5bce50fc0989d7b786ecc9af224567731f6cb23e/test/unit/APIConsumer_unit_test.js#L31) from the hardhat starter kit for an example of this

Comment: Thanks Harry for answering my post. Your post helped me explore the callback logic further. 

In the end, I ended up extracting the Chainlink-specific code (`sendChainlinkRequestTo(...)` & `receivePriceCallback(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _newPrice)` into a separate contract `ChainlinkOracleRequester` - enough to handle the outbound request and the incoming callback.

My `receivePriceCallback` is very light and calls a separate `priceReceiver.receivePrice(_requestId, _newPrice);` which I can test in isolation.

Comment: no worries, Ijonas, glad my response added some value!